# How do I get gradle (android studio) to put a .zip file in my app's lib/ directory?

Tags: android

I need to put a zip file in the lib/ directory of my app (crystax's embedded python expects it to be there), but it looks like the android studio gradle build scripts will only copy files that start with "lib" and end with ".so". I tried putting the file in assets/ and copying it at runtime but it looks like the lib/ directory isn't writable.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to put a zip file in the lib/ directory of my app.

Something like this:

```
task copyZipToLib(type: Copy) {
    // Copy the built zip to the lib folder
    from 'build/intermediates/dex/'
    into 'lib'
    include '*.zip'
}
```